# apollo beginner: cannot read data back from cache

Tags: apollo, react-apollo

I have this code to control a search field's value

```
const GET_SHOP_FILTER = gql`
  query getFilter {
    name @client
  }
`;

class ShopSuggestBox extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
                <div>
                    <div className="name">
                        <Query query={GET_SHOP_FILTER}>
                            {({data, client}) => (
                                    <div>
                                        data is {JSON.stringify(data)}
                                    <input
                                           onChange={e => {
                                               client.writeData({data: {name: e.target.value}})
                                           }} ...//not relevant
```

My issue is that I get these errors:

[GraphQL error]: Message: Cannot query field "name" on type "Query"., Location: [object Object], Path: undefined
index.js:63 [GraphQL error]: Message: Unknown directive "client"., Location: [object Object], Path: undefined

My understanding is that the directive @client is not interpreted. What did I miss please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok

The issue is that even though the doc says resolvers is not required, you must provide an empty resolver to have it work.

I modified the code as following (so the [doc](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/local-state.html) is wrong)

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
    //uri: "http://localhost:4000/graphql"
//  cache,

    clientState: {
        defaults: {
            name: "my",
            city: "",
            selectedId: null,
            previewId: null,
            selectedComplaintId: null,
        }, resolvers: {}
    }
});
```